# Compare a PostgreSQL Array with a given array in case insensitive way with Node.Js Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to make a generic filter, so it would be great if I could do this one with Sequelize and not with script. What I need is to check if the countries of the user overlaps with the given array. The check should be case insensitive. Is that possible?

```
const users = await User.findAll({
    where: {
        countries: { [Op.overlap]: ['GB', 'DE', 'ES'] }
    }
});
```

Here `countries` column contains array of strings.

Comment: So what do you actually get when you run it?  Please review [ask]. Following that as a template for your question greatly enhances your change of getting a satisfactory answer.

Comment: I get the expected result. I get all the users that has any of the countries from the array (i.e GB, DE, ES). What I need is do the check in  case insensitive way.